# Как каждый раз вызывать функцию с разной задержкой?

Tags: javascript

К примеру у меня есть функция:

```
function Test (){
  var Sector = document.getElementById("Sector");
  var Window = document.createElement("div");
  Sector.appendChild(Window);
}
```

И её нужно вызвать сначала с задержкой 20 потом 40 и т.д.

Comment: 20 чего? Ms, s, hours, years?

Comment: 20 - чего? (576 символов осталось)

Comment: миллисекунд (Но это не имеет значение)

Comment: Как это - не имеет значения?

Comment: В данном вопросе меня интересует, как это реализовать. А исправить setTimeOut(Test(),9999999) на setTimeOut(Test(),20) много ума не надо.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Test(delay){
  var Sector = document.getElementById("Sector");
  var Window = document.createElement("div");
  Sector.appendChild(Window);

  setTimeout(function(){ Test(delay + 20); }, delay + 20);
}

setTimeout(function(){ Test(20); }, 20);
```

Comment: Спасибо! за рекурсию:D

Answer (score 1):

```js
let time = 20;

setTimeout(function(){
  test(time);
  time *= 2;
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, time);
}, time);

function test(time){
  console.info('Вызвано с задержкой ' + time + 'ms!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Test() {
    var time = 20;
    var multiplier = 2;

    setTimeout(function run() {
        var Sector = document.getElementById("Sector");
        var Window = document.createElement("div");
        Sector.appendChild(Window);

        // Можно добавить любое условие
        if (Sector.children.length < 30 || time < 100000) {
            time *= multiplier;
            setTimeout(run, time);
        }
    }, time)
}
```